# Trouble solving integral with parameters

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to solve this integral for school and I cant wrap my head around a good solution.I have tried substitution,the method which you turn the $\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)*(x^2+b^2)}$ into sums and I am fairly certain I am going to have to split the integral into (-inf) to c and c to (+inf)

$\int_{-∞}^{+∞}\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})*(x^{2}+b^{2})}dx$

Domain of a,b is R*,where absolute a!= absolute b

I typed it into latex but it isnt appearing as math,I dont really know why.Hope you guys can help!

Comment: Here is the integral, I do not know the MathJax for infinity, by copying the symbol: $\int_{-∞}^{+ ∞}\frac{1}{(x^{2}+a^{2})*(x^{2}+b^{2})}dx$

Comment: Hey @TymaGaidash , can you comment the link of mathjax formatting rules .

Comment: @Sukhoi234 Great idea! [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that$$\frac1{(x^2+a^2)(x^2+b^2)}=\frac1{a^2-b^2}\left(\frac1{x^2+b^2}-\frac1{x^2+a^2}\right).$$

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UlPGuJV hows this?

Comment: What was I supposed to see there?

Comment: I sent my solution,let me try again: https://imgur.com/a/hiKhnwK

Comment: Why don't you *type* the solution?

Comment: I type really slowly,and also had to write the solution in paper for class so I thought it would be easier,does the link still not work?

Comment: I can see it now. And, yes, that answer is correct.

Comment: Great,thank you very much for your tip!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.